# Brokerage in US Bank Won't Print TOD name on Monthly Statement

Tags: united-states, brokerage, estate-planning, death, beneficiaries

I am in USA and have Brokerage account with Bank. When I opened account, I said who it should Transfer On Death (TOD).

When I get monthly statement, it said "TOD ", but it does not print name of TOD beneficiary.

When I asked the Brokerage, the person said they used to print name of TOD beneficiary, but now they don't because it is a security issue.

Then I asked how will my Beneficiary claim what is rightfully hers in the event something happens to me. The Brokerage person said they will mail out a letter stating the full name and details of my TOD Beneficiary. I hope this is true.

But my question is, why not print TOD beneficiary on the monthly statement and make it easier for the customer. Their reason for "Security" seems bogus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my question is, why not print TOD beneficiary on the monthly
> statement and make it easier for the customer. Their reason for
> "Security" seems bogus.

They have been moving away from having too much personal data on the bank statement. My current monthly PDF listing I get from the credit union doesn't even include the full account account numbers. Which get even more confusing when they went with seemingly random numbers on the newer account, so that the account number for the checking account looks nothing like the account number of the savings account.

With a TOD account you are responsible for making sure that the person/people know they are listed on the account. The full information is stored by the bank.